# If I need a database view or not?

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description=models.TextField()
    #some more fields

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company=models.ForeignKey(Company)
    #some more fields

class Category(models.Model):
    parent=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    products=models.ManyToManyField(Product,null=True,blank=True)
    #some more fields
```

as U can see each company has a list of product and each product belongs to some categories,I'm going to get the list of categories of each company using `company pk`,what's the best practice?should I define a database view?how can I do this?

Note:I've not ever used database view in django,I searched about it and that doesn't sound easy to me!

Comment: What's your question? How to get the categories that match a company?

Comment: yes,the best practice to do that!

Answer (score 2):

I always try to avoid using database views, stored procedures and in general stuff that 'lives' in the database itself rather than in the application code-base for the simple reason that it is very hard to maintain (and also you say good bye to database agnostic applications).

My advice here is to stick with django orm (which can do a lot) and only if you unable to get decent performances or if you need some advanced feature available through stored procedures/views only then to go for that solution.

Using views in django is quite easy.

Say you have 1 view to query, you create the view on the db then you write the model with fields matching the view' columns (name and type).

**UPDATE**:
You then need to set the table name as the view name in meta class definition.

After that you need to tell django not to write on that and to not try to create a table for the view model, luckily there is a conf for that:

```
class ViewModel(models.Model):
    ... view columns ...

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'view_name'
        managed = False
```

Comment: the thing that I don't understand is that how to associate models with view?

Comment: @Asma sorry I forgot to mention that, you can see in the answer now :)

Comment: I can't see changes in answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea why you think you need a db view here. Generally, you don't use them with Django, since you do all the logic in Python via the ORM.

To get the list of categories for a company, you can just do:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(products__company=my_company)
```

where `my_company` is the Company instance you're interested in.

Comment: I don't emphasize on using view,I just wanna do this with a good performance,because I have several company each of theme with lots of products,tnx :)

Comment: this way doesn't have performance problem?If so U will use ORM.

Comment: @Asma Try it and see if you have performance problems. If you haven't – it is good performance.

Comment: @Daniel I think U are experienced and expert,it's why I asked U,the performance won't be clear while the website be in used for a long time,Do U have any suggestion?